# Accessing properties files outside the .jar?

Tags: java, properties, jar

I have a .jar file I'm putting together. I want to create a really really simple .properties file with configurable things like the user's name & other stuff, so that they can hand-edit rather than my having to include a GUI editor.

What I'd like to do is to be able to search, in this order:

1. a specified properties file (`args[0]`)
2. MyApp.properties in the current directory (the directory from which Java was called)
3. MyApp.properties in the user's directory (the [user.home](http://www.mindspring.com/~mgrand/java-system-properties.htm) system property?)
4. MyApp.properties in the directory where the application .jar is stored

I know how to access #1 and #3 (I think), but how can I determine at runtime #2 and #4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#2 is the ["user.dir"](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()) system property. #3 is the "user.home" property.

#4 is a bit of a kludge no matter how you approach it. Here's an alternate technique that works if you have a class loaded from a JAR not on the system classpath.

```
CodeSource src = MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
if (src != null) {
  URL url = new URL(src.getLocation(), "MyApp.properties");
  ...
} 
else {
  /* Fail... */
}
```

Comment: @erickson it works! but if I have MyApp.properties inside a jar and in the external directory(not inside any package). Then how to read it?

Answer (score 10):

For 4, you could try this.  Get the classpath:

```
String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
```

Then search it for the name of your application jar:

```
int jarPos = classpath.indexOf("application.jar");
```

Parse out the path leading up to it:

```
int jarPathPos = classpath.lastIndexOf(File.pathSeparatorChar, jarPos) + 1;
String path = classpath.substring(jarPathPos, jarPos);
```

Then append `MyApp.properties`.  Make sure to check for `jarPos == -1`, meaning the jar isn't found if the classpath (perhaps when running in your dev environment).

Comment: Been searching for this for 1 week, everywhere they said use `Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()`, which DOES NOT WORK!!! at least not on Mac from inside the Contents of an .app file... But this finally solved my problem... Thank you a lot...

Answer (score 6):

For the current working directory:

```
new File(".");
```

For a file named MyApp.properties in the current directory:

```
new File(new File("."), "MyApp.properties");
```

Comment: That works, but even shorter is to pass empty string (new File(""))