# How to get a path to a resource in a Java JAR file

Tags: java, resources, path

I am trying to get a path to a Resource but I have had no luck.

This works (both in IDE and with the JAR) but this way I can't get a path to a file, only the file contents:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
PrintInputStream(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("config/netclient.p"));
```

If I do this:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("config/netclient.p").getFile());
```

The result is: 
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/path/to/jarfile/bot.jar!/config/netclient.p (No such file or directory)`

Is there a way to get a path to a resource file?

Comment: May I ask why you would need the path?

Comment: Yes. I've got a class that I would like to work with both, a folder on the outside (in case I want to change some parameter of the config file) and a JAR that hides the implementation configuration files to the user (like a distributable JAR to all people).

Comment: So the class just receives a PATH to a file (the config file).

Comment: Then you should probably have that class deal with an input stream, which you can get from either source.

Comment: Yes, I know. But it would have been more clear and clean the other way. But thx anyway.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like option #4 in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775389/accessing-properties-files-outside-the-jar/775565

Comment: well, i have pretty much the same problem. i want to be able to bundle and image in a JAR and then at runtime use that image in a JTextPanel using HTML. HTML requires either a relative path (and set the document base to something appropriate) or an absolute path. Can you get that path for a file in a JAR?

Comment: No, you cant. You can get an InputStream of the file but you can't get a path.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This is deliberate.  The contents of the "file" may not be available as a file.  Remember you are dealing with classes and resources that may be part of a JAR file or other kind of resource. The classloader does not have to provide a file handle to the resource, for example the jar file may not have been expanded into individual files in the file system.

Anything you can do by getting a java.io.File could be done by copying the stream out into a temporary file and doing the same, if a java.io.File is absolutely necessary.

Comment: you can add 'rsrc:' when you call your resource in order to open it. like new File("rsrc:filename.txt") this will load filename.txt which is packed inside the root of your jar

Answer (score 77):

When loading a resource make sure you notice the difference between:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("com/myorg/foo.jpg") //relative path
```

and

```
getClass().getResource("/com/myorg/foo.jpg")); //note the slash at the beginning
```

I guess, this confusion is causing most of problems when loading a resource.

---

Also, when you're loading an image it's easier to use `getResourceAsStream()`:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/myorg/foo.jpg"));
```

When you really have to load a (non-image) file from a JAR archive, you might try this:

```
File file = null;
String resource = "/com/myorg/foo.xml";
URL res = getClass().getResource(resource);
if (res.getProtocol().equals("jar")) {
    try {
        InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream(resource);
        file = File.createTempFile("tempfile", ".tmp");
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int read;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = input.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.close();
        file.deleteOnExit();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
    }
} else {
    //this will probably work in your IDE, but not from a JAR
    file = new File(res.getFile());
}

if (file != null && !file.exists()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Error: File " + file + " not found!");
}
```

Comment: +1 This worked for me.  Make sure you place the files that you want to read in in the `bin` folder and go to the directory of the class loading in the resources before using the `/com/myorg/filename.ext' path.

Comment: +1 This also works for me... I do understand that there might be some security risks related to this approach, so application owners need to be aware of that.

Comment: could you clarify this statement "It's always better to load a resource with getResourceAsStream()" ? How can this provide a solution to the problem?

Comment: @LucaS. That was meant just for the case of images, sorry it wasn't very clear. The approach should be platform independent, though it's a bit hacky way.

Comment: @LucasA Could you clarify the risks you mentioned?

Comment: i'm reading a wav file from my jar file and wrote it like in your example to my tmp dir. but the files are different. what happened and what can i do to prevent this?

Comment: never mind, in my pom i forgot to exclude wav files from filtering :'(

Comment: If you want to get a file in e.g. the root of the jar, an absolute path should be specified. Also, *any* class will do; example: URL url = Object.class.getResource("/" + filename);

Answer (score 39):

The one line answer is -

```
String path = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(<resourceFileName>).toExternalForm()
```

Basically [`getResource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) method gives the URL. From this URL you can extract the path by calling [`toExternalForm()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#toExternalForm--).

Comment: While running from my environment (IntelliJ) this produces a simple file URL which works in all cases.  However, when running from the jar itself, I get a URI similar to jar:file:/path/to/jar/jarname.jar!/file_in_jar.mp4.  Not everything can utilize a URI that begins with jar.  Case in point JavaFX Media.

Comment: I like this answer best. Granted, in most cases it may be preferable to simply grab the InputStream to the resource when it's in a jar file, but if for some reason you really need the path, this is what works. I needed the path to give to a third-party object. So, thanks!

Comment: the above solution does not work while in IDE, in Intellijit adds `file:/` to path , which works in jar but not in IDE

Answer (score 14):

I spent a while messing around with this problem, because no solution I found actually worked, strangely enough! The working directory is frequently not the directory of the JAR, especially if a JAR (or any program, for that matter) is run from the Start Menu under Windows. So here is what I did, and it works for .class files run from outside a JAR just as well as it works for a JAR. (I only tested it under Windows 7.)

```
try {
    //Attempt to get the path of the actual JAR file, because the working directory is frequently not where the file is.
    //Example: file:/D:/all/Java/TitanWaterworks/TitanWaterworks-en.jar!/TitanWaterworks.class
    //Another example: /D:/all/Java/TitanWaterworks/TitanWaterworks.class
    PROGRAM_DIRECTORY = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("TitanWaterworks.class").getPath(); // Gets the path of the class or jar.

    //Find the last ! and cut it off at that location. If this isn't being run from a jar, there is no !, so it'll cause an exception, which is fine.
    try {
        PROGRAM_DIRECTORY = PROGRAM_DIRECTORY.substring(0, PROGRAM_DIRECTORY.lastIndexOf('!'));
    } catch (Exception e) { }

    //Find the last / and cut it off at that location.
    PROGRAM_DIRECTORY = PROGRAM_DIRECTORY.substring(0, PROGRAM_DIRECTORY.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    //If it starts with /, cut it off.
    if (PROGRAM_DIRECTORY.startsWith("/")) PROGRAM_DIRECTORY = PROGRAM_DIRECTORY.substring(1, PROGRAM_DIRECTORY.length());
    //If it starts with file:/, cut that off, too.
    if (PROGRAM_DIRECTORY.startsWith("file:/")) PROGRAM_DIRECTORY = PROGRAM_DIRECTORY.substring(6, PROGRAM_DIRECTORY.length());
} catch (Exception e) {
    PROGRAM_DIRECTORY = ""; //Current working directory instead.
}
```

Answer (score 10):

This is same code from user Tombart with stream flush and close to avoid incomplete temporary file content copy from jar resource and to have unique temp file names.

```
File file = null;
String resource = "/view/Trial_main.html" ;
URL res = getClass().getResource(resource);
if (res.toString().startsWith("jar:")) {
    try {
        InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream(resource);
        file = File.createTempFile(new Date().getTime()+"", ".html");
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int read;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = input.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        input.close();
        file.deleteOnExit();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
} else {
    //this will probably work in your IDE, but not from a JAR
    file = new File(res.getFile());
}
```

Answer (score 8):

if `netclient.p` is inside a JAR file, it won't have a path because that file is located inside other file. in that case, the best path you can have is really `file:/path/to/jarfile/bot.jar!/config/netclient.p`.

Comment: When I try and convert a URL of this format (...bot.jar!/config/...) to URI it says that the path is not hierarchical.

Answer (score 7):

You need to understand the path within the jar file.
Simply refer to it relative.   So if you have a file (myfile.txt), located in foo.jar under the `\src\main\resources` directory (maven style).  You would refer to it like:

```
src/main/resources/myfile.txt
```

If you dump your jar using `jar -tvf myjar.jar`  you will see the output and the relative path within the jar file, and use the FORWARD SLASHES.

Comment: You indeed have to use forward slashes, even on Windows. That implies that you cannot use `File.separator`.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I have used a URL object instead Path.

**File**

```
File file = new File("my_path");
URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
```

**Resource in classpath using classloader**

```
URL url = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("resource_name")
```

When I need to read the content, I can use the following code:

```
InputStream stream = url.openStream();
```

And you can access the content using an InputStream.

Answer (score 4):

follow code!

## /src/main/resources/file

```java
streamToFile(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file"))

public static File streamToFile(InputStream in) {
    if (in == null) {
        return null;
    }

    try {
        File f = File.createTempFile(String.valueOf(in.hashCode()), ".tmp");
        f.deleteOnExit();

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        return f;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A File is an abstraction for a file in a filesystem, and the filesystems don't know anything about what are the contents of a JAR.

Try with an URI, I think there's a jar:// protocol that might be useful for your purpouses.

Answer (score 1):

The following path worked for me: `classpath:/path/to/resource/in/jar`

Comment: @Anatoly Could you please share more datails on above

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final String FILE_LOCATION = "com/input/file/somefile.txt";

//Method Body


InputStream invalidCharacterInputStream = URLClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(FILE_LOCATION);
```

Getting this from **`getSystemResourceAsStream`** is the best option.  By getting the inputstream rather than the file or the URL, works in a JAR file and as stand alone.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a little late but you may use my library [KResourceLoader](https://github.com/lamba92/KResourceLoader) to get a resource from your jar:

```
File resource = getResource("file.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

When in a `jar` file, the resource is located absolutely in the package hierarchy (not file system hierarchy). So if you have class `com.example.Sweet` loading a resource named `./default.conf` then the resource's name is specified as `/com/example/default.conf`.

But if it's in a jar then it's not a File ...

Answer (score 0):

Inside your ressources folder (java/main/resources) of your jar add your file (we assume that you have added an xml file named ***imports.xml***), after that you inject `ResourceLoader` if you use spring like bellow

```
@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
```

inside tour function write the bellow code in order to load file:

```
    Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:imports.xml");
    try{
        File file;
        file = resource.getFile();//will load the file
...
    }catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this method can be used for quick solution.

```
public class TestUtility
{ 
    public static File getInternalResource(String relativePath)
    {
        File resourceFile = null;
        URL location = TestUtility.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
        String codeLocation = location.toString();
        try{
            if (codeLocation.endsWith(".jar"){
                //Call from jar
                Path path = Paths.get(location.toURI()).resolve("../classes/" + relativePath).normalize();
                resourceFile = path.toFile();
            }else{
                //Call from IDE
                resourceFile = new File(TestUtility.class.getClassLoader().getResource(relativePath).getPath());
            }
        }catch(URISyntaxException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resourceFile;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you omitting some context? This gives me: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.security.CodeSource java.security.ProtectionDomain.getCodeSource()' on a null object reference`

Comment: I edited the answer and wrote the whole method which i used in a software

Answer (score 0):

This Class function can get absolute file path by relative file path in .jar file.

```
public class Utility {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Utility utility = new Utility();
        String absolutePath = utility.getAbsolutePath("./absolute/path/to/file");
    }

    public String getAbsolutePath(String relativeFilePath) throws IOException {
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource(relativeFilePath);
        return url.getPath();
    }
}
```

If target file is same directory with `Utility.java`, your input will be `./file.txt`.

When you input only `/` on  getAbsolutePath(), it returns `/Users/user/PROJECT_NAME/target/classes/`. This means you can select the file like this `/com/example/file.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to take the URL:

```
URL myUrl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(<resource>);
```

Then you need to check if you are asking the path from inside a jar, or from the IDE. The `getPath()` method removes the protocol part from the URL and it works from IDE where the protocol is `file:<path>` but not in jar case where you must use `toExternalForm()` that maintains the protocol part: `jar:<path>!/{entry}`
this is the solution:

```
String urlPath = ("jar".equals(myUrl.getProtocol())) ? myUrl.toExternalForm() : myUrl.getPath();
```