# Java Jar file: use resource errors: URI is not hierarchical

Tags: java, deployment, resources, executable-jar

I have deployed my app to jar file. When I need to copy data from one file of resource to outside of jar file, I do this code:

```
URL resourceUrl = getClass().getResource("/resource/data.sav");
File src = new File(resourceUrl.toURI()); //ERROR HERE
File dst = new File(CurrentPath()+"data.sav");  //CurrentPath: path of jar file don't include jar file name
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);
 // some excute code here
```

The error I have met is: `URI is not hierarchical`. this error I don't meet when run in IDE.

If I change above code as some help on other post on StackOverFlow:

```
InputStream in = Model.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/resource/data.sav");
File dst = new File(CurrentPath() + "data.sav");
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);
//....
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) { //NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
  //....
}
```

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You cannot do this

```
File src = new File(resourceUrl.toURI()); //ERROR HERE
```

it is not a file!
When you run from the ide you don't have any error, because you don't run a jar file. In the IDE classes and resources are extracted on the file system.

But you can open an `InputStream` in this way:

```
InputStream in = Model.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/data.sav");
```

Remove `"/resource"`. Generally the IDEs separates on file system classes and resources. But when the jar is created they are put all together. So the folder level `"/resource"` is used only for classes and resources separation.

When you get a resource from classloader you have to specify the path that the resource has inside the jar, that is the real package hierarchy.

Comment: I have tried again your way (is my second code above), but when it is go through: `in.read(buf)` ---> I meet null point exception. :( @:resource is a folder in my project. it has same hierarchy with other package. So, I need I must include `resource`

Comment: post the hierarchy of your project

Comment: But what if i really NEED an "File" object... ?

Comment: You cannot have a File object because a resource is not necessary a file.

Comment: Could you please provide more details on that? When is a ressource not a file?

Comment: When the resource is located in a jar, for example, the single `resource` is a Jar Entry object (not a file on file system), and cannot be used to create an instance of `java.io.File` class

Comment: @dash1e ^ This is not true - see my answer

Comment: it works for me without the slash: "data.sav" instead of "/data.sav"

Comment: @Daniel it depends on where you put your resource. You can use `data.sav` without the starting `/` if you put your resource file in the same package of your class file. But in the question the `data.sav` is in the root package so in that case he needs to prepend `/`.

Comment: Just like TekTimmy: But what if I REALLY NEED a file ?
I'm in a email sending process and we wanna join a logo file picture to email. The pict is in the jar and I have to give it to the datasource as a File, not an InputStream...

Comment: @JNGerbaux i also wanted a `File` object so i created temp `File` and copied content from `InputStream` to File object. using `FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, file);`

Comment: @VishalPatel that is the right approach if you need the file

Answer (score 29):

If for some reason you really need to create a `java.io.File` object to point to a resource inside of a Jar file, the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27149287/155167

```
File f = new File(getClass().getResource("/MyResource").toExternalForm());
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is a solution for Eclipse RCP / Plugin developers:

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("resource_from_some_plugin");
URL fileURL = bundle.getEntry("files/test.txt");
File file = null;
try {
   URL resolvedFileURL = FileLocator.toFileURL(fileURL);

   // We need to use the 3-arg constructor of URI in order to properly escape file system chars
   URI resolvedURI = new URI(resolvedFileURL.getProtocol(), resolvedFileURL.getPath(), null);
   File file = new File(resolvedURI);
} catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

It's very important to use `FileLocator.toFileURL(fileURL)` rather than `resolve(fileURL)`
, cause when the plugin is packed into a jar this will cause Eclipse to create an unpacked version in a temporary location so that the object can be accessed using File. For instance, I guess Lars Vogel has an error in his article - http://blog.vogella.com/2010/07/06/reading-resources-from-plugin/

Comment: What is Platform class? Some non-rt library needed?

Comment: @AndreyP this solution is for eclipse rcp plugin developers. I would recommend to try getResourceAsStream(...) approach

Comment: In my maven-built RCP E4 application, jar-bundled binary files need to be extracted and opened. Your solution finally enabled me to do so and open `file.getAbsolutePath()` in the OS default browser.

Comment: Thanks ! This answer was very helpful, since I got a bug with FileLocator.resolve. I could create the File object directly with :
`File f = new File(FileLocator.toFileURL(resolvedFileURL).toURI());`

Answer (score 1):

I got a similiar issues before, and I used the code:

```java
new File(new URI(url.toString().replace(" ","%20")).getSchemeSpecificPart());
```

instead of the code :

```java
new File(new URI(url.toURI())
```

to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

While I stumbled upon this problem myself I'd like to add another option (to the otherwise perfect explanation from @dash1e):

Export the plugin as a folder (not a jar) by adding:

```
Eclipse-BundleShape: dir
```

to your `MANIFEST.MF`.

At least when you export your RCP app with the export wizard (based on a `*.product`) file this gets respected and will produce a folder.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the general answers, you can get "URI is not hierarchical" from **Unitils** library attempting to load a *dataset* off a `.jar` file. It may happen when you keep datasets in one maven submodule, but actual tests in another.

There is even a [bug UNI-197](https://unitils.atlassian.net/browse/UNI-197) filed.