# Maven Assembly Plugin : Resources are copied at root of jar

Tags: java, maven, jar

I'm using the **maven-assembly-plugin** to build a **Java 8** project, and package it as a **JAR** file.

I've got several resources located at `src/main/resources` (usual maven resources directory).
When the JAR is created, all resources files under `src/main/resources` are copied at the root of the JAR.

In the code, I'm trying to open files using `FileInputStream` that are located in `src/main/resources`, and it works great when running the project without packaging it as a JAR file. However, when I'm running the project from the JAR file, I get many `FileNotFoundException` because my resources are not anymore at `src/main/resources`, but at `${project.basedir}` instead.

I'd like to have them located at `src/main/resources` in the JAR file. Is it possible?

My build configuration is as follow:

```
   <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>

                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>EmployProject.TestAlgo</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>TestAlgo</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>

                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

    </build>
```

**Edit**

If it's not possible, what, in my code, should I use to access my resources files?

Comment: Hmm yeah, why should I use it? What are the benefits, and how would it solve my problem?

Comment: My resources files are included in the JAR. The problem is that they are put at the root of my project, and, when in the code I try to access them using getClass().getResource(fileName), it returns null because it can't find the file.

Comment: First removed `sourceDirectory` and resources configuration cause those are both the defaults...so don't configure it...Apart from that by default resources are at the root of your jar file which means you have to use `getResourceAsStream("/property.properties")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @khmarbaise and this post: [Accessing a Java Resource as a File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605207/accessing-a-java-resource-as-a-file)

I figured out I was using the wrong API to open resources.
Resources in a JAR are not files, thus I changed:

```
XMLDecoder xmlDec = new XMLDecoder(new InputFileStream(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName))
```

to:

```
InputStream in = EnumTools.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(in);
```