# How to get resource from another plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I have 2 plugins **A** and **B**. In the MANIFEST.MF of the **A** I do have plugin **B** in a **Require-Bundle** section. But when I try to get **B's** resource from **A** like

```java
ClassFromA.class.getClassLoader().getResource('resource_from_B')
```

I am getting **null**. If I put **B's** resourсe (folder) to **A's** root everything works like a charm. Am I missing something?

NOTE: I read Lars Vogel's [article](http://blog.vogella.com/2010/07/06/reading-resources-from-plugin/)

```java
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("de.vogella.example.readfile");
URL fileURL = bundle.getEntry("files/test.txt");
File file = null;
try {
    file = new File(FileLocator.resolve(fileURL).toURI());
} catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

^this solution works when I run my plugin from eclipse, but when I pack it to jar and try to install from the local update site I'm getting

```java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
```

P.S. I have also read several relative questions on the StackOverflow but wasn't able to find the answer:

- [Java Jar file: use resource errors: URI is not hierarchical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144210/java-jar-file-use-resource-errors-uri-is-not-hierarchical)
- [Why is my URI not hierarchical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055189/why-my-uri-is-not-hierarchical)

SOLUTION:
Many thanks to @greg-449. So the correct code is:

```java
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("resource_from_some_plugin");
URL fileURL = bundle.getEntry("files/test.txt");
File file = null;
try {
   URL resolvedFileURL = FileLocator.toFileURL(fileURL);

   // We need to use the 3-arg constructor of URI in order to properly escape file system chars
   URI resolvedURI = new URI(resolvedFileURL.getProtocol(), resolvedFileURL.getPath(), null);
   File file = new File(resolvedURI);
} catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

NOTE: also it's **very important** to use the 3-arg constructor of URI in order to properly escape file system chars.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```java
FileLocator.toFileURL(fileURL)
```

rather than `FileLocator.resolve(fileURL)` when you want to use the URL with `File`.

When the plugin is packed into a jar this will cause Eclipse to create an unpacked version in a temporary location so that the object can be accessed using `File`.

Comment: oh my! You are just awesome :-)

Comment: @Lars Vogel I guess you do have an error in your article - http://blog.vogella.com/2010/07/06/reading-resources-from-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [Bundle.getResource](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29)? That seems to be the OSGi way to access resources.

Your first attempt might work if you use a `ClassFromB.class.getClassLoader` instead of `A`.

Comment: @lulian Dragos, I do not have any classes in **B**, only resources