# "URI is not hierarchical" when loading resource

Tags: java, resources, uri, classloader, illegalargumentexception

I need the URI of a file (which I put in the resources directory). If I use

```
MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource(resource)
```

I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
```

Otherwise, if I use `ClassLoader.getSystemResource(resource)` it returns `null`.

Comment: Can you provide the URI you are using?

Comment: file:/Users/user1/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea14/plugins-sandbox/plugins/plugin/classes/disconnected.png
That's the URI I get when running from the IDE. It runs like it should. But when I generate a jar and try to run it, it fails.

Comment: Try `new File(MyClass.class.getResource(resource).getPath()).toURI()` or `new File(MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource(resource).getPath()).toURI()`

Comment: It should be relative to the top level of the jar file, not an absolute pathname. Also, I am not sure you want ir need the "file:" prefix.

Comment: See related q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573679/open-resource-with-relative-path-in-java

Comment: @user3218114, it works, but it doesn't load the image when running from a jar.

Comment: you should use `getResourceAsStream()`

Comment: I can't. How can I convert an inputstream to a file/uri?

Answer (score 1):

Are you loading the file from inside a jar? If so, the OS is unable to form a java `File` instance from inside a jar. To be able to load it, try open it as a Stream. "`filepath`" should start with a "`/`".

```
MyClass.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream( filepath );
```

Comment: This may not work as intended in newer JVM implementations.

Answer (score -1):

You should be using

> getResourceAsStream(...);

when the resource is bundled as a jar/war or any other single file package for that matter.

See the thing is, a jar is a single file (kind of like a zip file) holding lots of files together. From Os's pov, its a single file and if you want to access a part of the file(your image file) you must use it as a stream.

Comment: Can you please provide sources for your answers. I think your answer got downvoted exactly for this, cause it is an almost exact copy of another user's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18055478/19032206