# Problems with running jar within a jar - IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have jar file Test2 contained in jar file Test1, and I execute Test1. When I try to execute Test2 using `java.awt.Desktop` I get the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical` exception and message. I can do it successfully when I have Test2 separate from Test1 (i.e. Test2 in a different folder) and access it like below:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("path-to-file\\Test2.jar"));
```

And I can do the following from my IDE without any problems:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(Test.class.getResource("Test2.jar").toURI()));
```

I have problems running Test2 when I run the jar file Test1 using the above line of code.

Through research, I learned that you have to do something like [`InputStream is = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(...);`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18055478/3386144). What I couldn't figure out, however, is *what*, if anything, you have to do with this `InputStream` to successfully execute a jar from within a jar, or what this `InputStream` does to make the URI hierarchical. So far this is I came up with (I don't know if I even have the first file correct):

```
InputStream is = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Test2.jar");
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(Test.class.getResource("Test2.jar").toURI()));
```

Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: AFAIK you **cannot** execute a jar within a jar, why do you want to?

Comment: Simply put, I have this project originally created into a jar that I revamped and modified (and I made the new version into a jar as well), and I wanted to give users the option to use the previous version by programmatically running the old jar file.

Comment: The jar seems to be in your project folder but is it packaged into your final jar?

Comment: @user2924010 Do you mean packaged with all the other classes and the manifest file? If so, yes.

Comment: I meant like putting the jar in a in the other jar. A jar is a zip. So if you put lib.jar into final.jar, maybe it'll work.

Comment: I believe OP wants to programmatically select his entry-point. Obviously you might select an alternate `Main-Class` from the command line, but I don't think you can embed a jar within a jar and execute the embedded jar from the jar it is embedded in... at least, not without writing a custom container.