# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical executable jar file

Tags: java

I searched for a solution to my problem but I could not find an answer.
In a client server chat application the client wants to get the server's public key which is stored in a Server.cer file.

```
URL resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Server.cer");
File file = new File(resource.toURI());
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
while(bufferedInputStream.available() > 0){
    certificate = cf.generateCertificate(bufferedInputStream);
}
publicKey = certificate.getPublicKey();
```

This works fine when I run my class in Eclipse but when I export it as an executable jar file I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
```

Could you please help me resolve this problem because I need the executable jar file to work.

Comment: This should be related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055189/why-my-uri-is-not-hierarchical

Comment: Guys, Can this be voted to be closed as duplicate?

Comment: Voted to close as a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem. This is how I did it.

```
    Certificate certificate = null;

    //Get server's public key which is stored in a file called Server.cer (RSA-1024 bit).
    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Server.cer");
    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    while(bufferedInputStream.available() > 0){
        certificate = cf.generateCertificate(bufferedInputStream);
    }
    publicKey = certificate.getPublicKey();

    bufferedInputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();
```