# URI is not hierarchical - Creating infafas connection using JDBC

Tags: java

My question is very specific to the problem I am recently facing while connecting to Informatica Data Vault (IDV) using infa-fas driver in java.

To give a background : IDV is a file system and stores structured & unstructured data in a format similar to common databases like Oracle. To connect I am using the following code :

```
String username = buttonGroup.getSelection().getActionCommand(); // Selecting user from a radioButton
String pwd = new String(password.getPassword()); // Password from JPassword Field
String host = hostName.getText();   // Host and Database name resp.             
String database = dbName.getText();
// URL for connecting to IDV
String url = "jdbc:infafas:"+"//"+username+":"+pwd+"@"+host+":8501"+"/"+database;
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.informatica.fas.jdbc.Driver()); // Driver class
```

When I run this utility using Eclipse IDE, I am able to connect to the db and query as well. But when packaged as a jar, it gives the below error :

Please let me know where I am wrong or what modifications can be done.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
        at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.informatica.fas.jdbc.FASConnection.<init>(FASConnection.java:465)
        at com.informatica.fas.jdbc.FASDriver.connect(FASDriver.java:168)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.rbs.gui.TargetConnectionPanel$2.actionPerformed(TargetConnectionP
anel.java:165)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: just posted the code

Comment: Is your IDV file located in resource folder? if not, where is it?

Comment: @Emad - i've configured the Build path with the required jar files (infafas.jar) in eclipse which is present in my local system directory

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055189/why-my-uri-is-not-hierarchical

Comment: @Emad The link is for the files present in resource folder.In my case, it is about the jar file throwing error when we try to register the Driver class (last line in the above code). Pls let me know any way to allow access to this jar since other jars r very much accessible