# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical (in deployed application)

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, war, java-io

I have deployed my app to jar file. I want to generate and store PDF in resource folder of my application, Everything is working for me in development but when I deployed I got error in live application

following is my code

```
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/templates");
        parentDirectory = new File(new URI(url.toString()));
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(parentDirectory.toString()+"/"+quoteNumber+".pdf");
```

everything is working fine and created PDf file successfully when I run my application from Eclips but I deploye application WAR file in server I got this error

my error full log is following

> 2018-03-09 18:23:31.033 ERROR 6 --- [ XNIO-2 task-13]
>   o.z.p.spring.web.advice.AdviceTrait      : Internal Server Error
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical   at
>   java.io.File.(File.java:418)    at
>   com.beequote.web.rest.QuotebuilderResource.Quote(QuotebuilderResource.java:338)
>     at
>   com.beequote.web.rest.QuotebuilderResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7c210806.invoke()
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>     at
>   com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:48)
>     at
>   com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:34)
>     at
>   com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.invoke(AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.java:59)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
>     at
>   com.beequote.web.rest.QuotebuilderResource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c16579cf.Quote()
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
>     at
>   com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:111)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:59)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at com.beequote.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:36)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:64)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:332)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

```
getResourceAsStream(...);
```

when the resource is bundled as a jar/war or any other single file package for that matter.

Comment: Can you please provide sources for your answers. Right now your answer is an almost exact copy of another user's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18055478/19032206

Answer (score 0):

Create the `OutputStream` with

```
OutputStream os = this.getClass()
    .getClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream("/templates/" + quoteNumber + ".pdf");
```

You want to store the pdf inside the jar, which is different from when running in your local environment (say with Eclipse) where the OS filesystem is used.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code to

```
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("/templates/"+quoteNumber+".pdf");
```