# Java - Convert Data URI to File

Tags: java

If I'm using Java and I have a `String` of a Data URI, is it possible to create a `File` from that `String` value?

For example, here's what I'm currently trying to do:

```
//A data URI representing a txt file 
String dataUri = "data:text/plain;base64,VGVzdGluZy4=";

//This line works fine. The URI is created
URI testURI = new URI(dataUri);

//This line throws this exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
File test = new File(testURI);
```

I've looked at posts related to the exception ([Why is my URI not hierarchical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055189/why-is-my-uri-not-hierarchical), and [Java Jar file: use resource errors: URI is not hierarchical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144210/java-jar-file-use-resource-errors-uri-is-not-hierarchical)), but neither of these original questions are trying to do what I'm trying to do. Also, I understand that the issue is because the `URI` is not in this form `C:\path\to\a\file.example` (hierarchical). This is clearly stated in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.net.URI)). So I understand that this is not a proper way to go about what I'm trying to do, I'm just not sure what else to try.

Is it possible to convert a data URI to a `File` (or perhaps a similar class) in Java?

Comment: This does seem to be a possible duplicate of that question in the sense that the accepted answer for that question is a general conversion of a base64 encoded file to a `byte[]`. However, you have to admit that the post is not very well named for that solution, which is arguably why I didn't find it myself.

Comment: Agreed. You should mark your question as duplicate now. :)

Comment: Ya know, I wasn't aware that I could do that? I learn something new here everyday. :) Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.