# How to execute integrationtests for own OData service in SAP Cloud SDK

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

We currently provide an own OData service in our Spring Boot application with the SAP Cloud Platform Provisioning SDK which is part of the SAP Cloud SDK. We are creating integration tests in the respective maven module, but when executing this via Maven it fails with the following stack trace:

```
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] ERROR com.sap.cloud.sdk.service.prov.v2.rt.cdx.CDXRuntimeDelegate - Error initializing the service <service-name>
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:418)
        at com.sap.cloud.sdk.service.prov.v2.rt.cdx.CDXRuntimeDelegate.getFilefromFileName(CDXRuntimeDelegate.java:410)
        at com.sap.cloud.sdk.service.prov.v2.rt.cdx.CDXRuntimeDelegate.getFileForService(CDXRuntimeDelegate.java:387)
        at com.sap.cloud.sdk.service.prov.v2.rt.cdx.CDXRuntimeDelegate.initialize(CDXRuntimeDelegate.java:252)
        at com.sap.cloud.sdk.service.prov.v2.rt.cdx.CDXRuntimeDelegate.getModelProvider(CDXRuntimeDelegate.java:204)
        at com.sap.gateway.core.api.provider.delegate.ProviderFactory.createModelProvider(ProviderFactory.java:202)
        at com.sap.gateway.core.api.provider.delegate.ProviderFactory.getEdmModelProvider(ProviderFactory.java:128)
        at com.sap.gateway.core.odata4sap.ServiceFactory.createService(ServiceFactory.java:135)
```

Looking at the code this seems to be related to the following post:

[Why is my URI not hierarchical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055189/why-is-my-uri-not-hierarchical)

In the SDK the OData EDMX file is read as a file however since during maven execution it is in a separate JAR file (of the application module) it cannot be accessed that way. Instead it would need to be read as a stream, which in turn seems to require some refactoring.

As a workaround I copied the EDMX file to the src/test/resources/edmx of the integration-tests module.

I'm now wondering if I am missing something here, or if the execution of the integration-tests as usually done per SAP Cloud SDK is not compatible with the provisioning framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not too familiar with the use case you explained, I would recommend checking out the [Maven documentation on additional resource folders](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html). You can probably point your *integration-tests* module to the respective `/resources` folder of *application* modules, in addition to its own `/resources` folder. I think relative paths should be possible.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I was thinking about automating the workaround as well, and this for me seems a really nice solution!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to what Alexander already posted, you could also automate the copying of the files via maven, like in this snippet:

```
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- Copying the edmx files to the integration-tests project -->
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/resources/edmx</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.parent.basedir}/srv/src/main/resources/edmx</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testResources</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testResources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```