# Maven - URI is non hierarchial

Tags: java, spring, maven

Im trying learn Spring and Maven but im having some trouble.

When I go to run my tests from the terminal using `mvn clean install` I'm getting this error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical . This is the block of code that throws the error :

```
LocationWeatherRootResponseTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("extent.xml")).toURI()
```

When I change the above code to the following Im getting a null pointer exception.

```
LocationWeatherRootResponseTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("extent.xml")))
```

**Update**

When I change the code to the below Im getting a new error.

```
    File file = new File(WeatherTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("extent.xml").getPath());        
Reporter.loadXMLConfig(file);
```

stacktrace :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/user/IdeaProjects/spring-cucumber-test-harness/common/target/common-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/extent.xml (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055189/why-is-my-uri-not-hierarchical https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144210/java-jar-file-use-resource-errors-uri-is-not-hierarchical Did you look at these?

Comment: yeah ive tried .toExternalForm() and FileLocator.toFileURL but neither of these approaches worked

Comment: I ran the following snippet and it passed. ``import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Objects;

public class MyTest {
    @Test
    void test() throws URISyntaxException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(MyTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("extent.xml")).toURI();
    }
}``

Comment: did you try to run it with mvn clean install - thats where its failing for me, I can right click and run it successfully. its only with maven it fails

Comment: its fine with mvn clean install as well.

Comment: Which version of maven you have?

Comment: Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.8, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64

Comment: I just noticed maven is using the Open JDK and not the same JDK as the IDE. Could this be part of the problem?

Comment: I fixed the open JDK issue, the URI error is still present tho

Comment: I did not anticipate issues due to JDK. It might be Maven or the surefire plugin that runs the tests. Can you try updating the Maven and use the latest version of the surefire plugin?

Comment: I appreciate all your help. I added the surefire plugin to the framework. Maven is already on the latest version. When I run the code with the old implementation Im getting the URI error. When I run the code with the updated version im getting a file not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue using `maven-remote-resources-plugin` . Now when I run `mvn clean install` on the master `POM` the framework runs from e2e.

In the module containing the resources I wanted to share, I added the following to the POM file

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bundle</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In the module where I want to use the resource. I added the following

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <resourceBundles>
                            <resourceBundle>{groupId}:{resource artifactId}:1.0-SNAPSHOT</resourceBundle>
                        </resourceBundles>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>process</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```