# Load font file from resources folder

Tags: java, file, fonts, pdfbox, truetype

I try to load a font file which is in resources folder:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/com/fuentes/fuente.ttf");
File file = new File(url.toURI());
newFont = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(documento, file);
```

but I get this error:

> URI is not hierarchical

Comment: This is not a PDFBox problem. See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144210/java-jar-file-use-resource-errors-uri-is-not-hierarchical

Comment: Check this project, solves resources folder scanning: https://github.com/fraballi/resources-folder-scanner

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
File file = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/com/fuentes/fuente.ttf").getFile());
```