# Extracting Folder from Resources to disk

Tags: java, file, resources, copy, extract

I am trying to copy the Files of a Resources Folder to disk.

```
        final URL url = TemplateUtils.class.getResource("/templates/");
        LOG.info(url);
        if (url != null) {
            final File dir = new File(url.toURI()); //Line 59

            this.copyFiles(dir.getAbsolutePath(), dir.getName()); //calls a recursive method to copy all Files in subfolders
```

Running this code in Eclipse everything is working fine, because the url is:

```
file:/home/tobias/git/myapp/target/classes/templates/
```

but after building and running the jar, I get the following error, because the url does not fit anymore:

```
jar:file:/home/tobias/myapp/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/templates/
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:418)
at myapp.utils.TemplateUtils.copyTemplates(TemplateUtils.java:59)
```

How do I fix the URI is not hierarchical Error?
I already tried to change like they said here: [Java Jar file: use resource errors: URI is not hierarchical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144210/java-jar-file-use-resource-errors-uri-is-not-hierarchical)
but then i get a NullPointer at this line:

```
URL resolvedFileURL = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);
```

How can I fix this? Maybe there is an easier way to extract this folder to disk?

**Solution** (but now only working from jar file and not from eclipse anymore):
using this class: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3923182/4125191

```
    final File path = new File(PathManager.INSTANCE.getRootPath()
            + "templates/");
    path.mkdirs();
    try {
        LOG.info("Copying Templates...");
        final Collection<String> fileList = ResourceList.getResources();
        for (final String s : fileList) {

            final File newFile = new File(path.toString() + File.separator
                    + StringUtils.substringAfterLast(s, File.separator));
            newFile.createNewFile();
            final String folder = StringUtils.substringAfterLast(
                    StringUtils.substringBeforeLast(s, File.separator),
                    File.separator);

            final InputStream inStream = TemplateUtils.class
                    .getResourceAsStream("/" + s);
            if (inStream != null) {
                Files.copy(inStream, newFile.toPath(),
                        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                inStream.close();
            }

            this.mapFile(folder, newFile);
        }
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

Comment: Resources in jar files are not files/directories. You cannot directly apply `File` methods to them. You may try to use the solution offered in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3923182/4125191) to access them through ZIP operations.

Comment: This answer is giving me the String of the path to the file in the resources. But I cannot make a File with that String, as you said.

Comment: The idea is to look for all the files in your folder by checking for `/template/*`, and then you can iterate on the resulting collection of strings, and use `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` to access the individual resources' contents.

Comment: Thanks, was now able to write a peace of code which is working from the jar! Had the wrong idea what to do with that.

Comment: @Tobi Then why don't you share your peace of code?