# Illegal Argument Exception: URI is not hierarchical with runable .jar file

Tags: java, eclipse

I know this question has been asked a bunch of times before, but I'm peeled through all the other threads and tried a bunch of stuff, but can't find anything that resolves my issue. I have a program that compiles and runs without issue in Eclipse, but when I export a runnable .jar file, it won't launch. I tried running it from the cmd prompt, and got the error `Illegal Argument Exception: URI in not hierarchical`. This is happening in an included sound file which I have as a classpath resource. The code is like this:

```
try {
    pop = new File(IntroView.class.getResource("/model/pop.wav")
                .toURI());
} catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

From what I've read it's a problem with the way that the file is being packed up into the .jar, but I'm having  a hard time wrapping my head around it. Can anybody shed some light on this and possibly provide a solution? Thanks.

Comment: see [Java Jar file: use resource errors: URI is not hierarchical](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144210/java-jar-file-use-resource-errors-uri-is-not-hierarchical)

Comment: I looked at those, and seeing as I require a file I would have to use the `Bundle` class. I looked around for the library to download so that I can use it, but couldn't find what I needed (or what I thought I needed anyway...).

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but it seems you cannot represent a File object from inside a JAR. When locating a file using File object it checks for file in the OS directory structure only. The File object can locate the JAR itself in a directory but not what's inside.

You can get the InputStream to the file inside JAR like this as stated in a few places:

```
InputStream input = PlaySound.class.getResourceAsStream("Kalimba.mp3");
```

You could have these options:

1. Read the file from JAR and write it outside in your directory and
   then get the File Object.
2. Extract the JAR to a folder and point to that with a File.
3. Simply get the InputStream and play the file as shown here:
       [How can I play sound in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26305)

Comment: I gave that a shot but it's giving me a `java.io.FileNotFound` exception, giving the path then `(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)`. That was right in Eclipse too, not even in the runnable .jar yet...

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I got it working, but it's not really an ideal solution. What I ended up doing is creating a folder within the project, but outside of the source. So before, the resources were in

```
Project/src/Model/pop.wav
```

Now they are in

```
Project/Resources/pop.wav
```

I then just accessed then like this

```
pop = new File("Resources/pop.wav");
```

So as this stands, it still only works when launching from the IDE, but what I did was add a new folder within the same folder that the `.jar` is being run from which contained all the same resource files. The file reference looks for `pop.wav` relative to whichever directory the program(either in the IDE of from the `.jar`) is being run from, so it finds the files in this new folder and works fine. I don't feel it's the prettiest solution, but it works anyway.