# URI is not hierarchical when loading file from .jar

Tags: java, io, uri, java-io

So I have a problem with loading a file when running my program from a jar file. I am aware that questions very similar to this exist but I can find none that work for me or do what I need. I would like to load an object file from a folder in my jar but when I do I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
        at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at bbsource.BouncyBallV5.loadLevels(BouncyBallV5.java:370)
        at bbsource.BouncyBallV5.<init>(BouncyBallV5.java:243)
        at BBDriver.main(BBDriver.java:18)
```

Line 370 is as follows

`initSource = new File(getClass().getResource("/resources/levels").toURI());`

I have no problems with this line when running from Eclipse but I am aware that things act differently in jar files. The folder hierarchy is:

- src

  - resources

    - levels

      - tier_one

        - Level1.cbbl
        - Level2.cbbl
      - tier_two

        - Level1.cbbl

levels is a directory that it will not let me access, and I'm not sure how to get it to work. I have seen suggestions such as using `InputStream` but I'm not sure how to use that and still treat it as a file from which I can read objects.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is because `/resources/levels` is a directory not a file. Check the answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144210/java-jar-file-use-resource-errors-uri-is-not-hierarchical)

Comment: And I use it as a directory to access it's sub directories and eventually it's files, but I need the directory-like structure for indexing reasons. And I'm still unsure how I would actually use `InputStream` for this. Would code on how I use `initSource` help?

Comment: Try using `initSource = new File(getClass().getResource("/resources/levels").getFile())`

Comment: This still works in Eclipse, but I still get an error when run as a jar from Command Prompt. However, this time the error is a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I managed to find a way around the problem by using a .zip file and a `ZipInputStream`. Thank you for your help though.