# Finding path to a file(geckodriver.exe) inside a running Jar

Tags: selenium, jar, executable-jar, geckodriver

I am using selenium FirefoxDriver, and need to configure the driver:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path_to_driver");
```

The problem is that when I try run the jar withouth the IDE, I get a error, because it can not access my driver (which is inside the jar) from the outside

I have a week now, every kind of help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot refer to a resource within a jar file the same way as you would from your IDE. A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144210/java-jar-file-use-resource-errors-uri-is-not-hierarchical)

**Alternative**

You can try [WebDriver Binary Downloader](https://github.com/prashant-ramcharan/webdriver-binary-downloader) which will automatically download and configure the **latest** driver binary for you.

There's no need to explicitly define the path or even have the binary in your project.

```
WebDriverBinaryDownloader.create().downloadLatestBinaryAndConfigure(BrowserType.FIREFOX);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: I just created a temp file and read it.

But damn had no idea WebDriver Binary Downloader existed, will defiantly try it out.