# How to specify the path correctly to open a file from a sub directory of my project?

Tags: java, resources, subdirectory

I have my project structure like this

--src

--------------resources

--------------saves

I use this subfolder at multiples times like this:

```
 File tempFile = new File("src/saves/" + videoName + ".json");
```

or sometimes like this :

```
ImageView icon = new ImageView("resources/edit.png");
```

and :

```
File f = new File("src/resources/zelda.mp4");
```

For some reasons it works for the `icon` but not for the video/file, when I try I get this error:

```
Caused by: MediaException: MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE : C:\Users\histackoverflow\IdeaProjects\project2\resources\zelda.mp4 (specified path can't be found)
```

so I want to know what is wrong in my way of using path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Edit: this works fine for referencing files in IDE. For appropriate file references in jar, follow this: [Java Jar file: use resource errors: URI is not hierarchical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144210/java-jar-file-use-resource-errors-uri-is-not-hierarchical)

I wouldn't recommend typing in the path as a String. A better way of loading files is placing them into recources (you already did that) and call the rescource by class reference and getting URI from it:

```
    InputStream file = new FileInputStream(getClass().getResource("/edit.png").getPath());
    Image image = new Image(file);
    ImageView icon = new ImageView(image);


    File f = new File(getClass().getResource("/zelda.mp4").toURI());
```

Make sure, that your directory with resources is marked as a resource directory.

Comment: I will suggest not to Copy paste the code, help the user who has asked the question with proper answer with relevant to his/her code. It is just a suggestion.

Comment: Yes, you can. But you probably need to add a slash before `saves`, this means `/saves/xy.json` is the path.

Comment: Okay I tried, inside the IDE it works, but when I tried with the .jar I have ```Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical```

Comment: Right, when creating a jar you cannot use URI. Try this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144210/java-jar-file-use-resource-errors-uri-is-not-hierarchical