# Java I/O help. Jar Cannot Open File: URI is Not Hierarchal

Tags: maven, io, apache-poi, uri, executable-jar

I have been searching for 3 days now nonstop looking at every post I can find. My program runs on IntelliJ, but cannot run on an executable. Your help would be appreciated :)

More importantly, where can I find a in depth user-friendly tutorial? Is there a course or book I can pay for? On Udemy, the java classes completely fail to mention I/O such as classpath and URI. TutorialsPoint briefly goes over I/O buts its not indepth. Did I miss something? Is there an easier way to do all this??

Similar posts that have not worked for me:
[Java Jar file: use resource errors: URI is not hierarchical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144210/java-jar-file-use-resource-errors-uri-is-not-hierarchical)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27149287/155167

I am trying to load an excel file. I am using Maven. Apache POI says it needs a File. So *InputStream does not work*. http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream

**When I java -jar jarFile, it gives me the error**:

```
C:\Users\1010\Documents\Personal\MonsterManager>java -jar monsterManagerVer3.jar

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical

        at java.base/java.io.File.<init>(File.java:421)
        at LoadExcel.<init>(LoadExcel.java:62)
        at monsterRunner.<init>(monsterRunner.java:13)
        at monsterRunner.main(monsterRunner.java:24)
```

**Here is the code**

```
public LoadExcel() throws IOException, URISyntaxException, InvalidFormatException {
        mNames = null;
        URL ins = this.getClass().getResource("/excel_List.xlsx");
        if (ins == null)
            throw new FileNotFoundException("The XLSX file didn't exist on the classpath");
        ins.toString().replace(" ","%20"); //<-Runs without this part

        File file = new File(ins.toURI()); //this is line 62


       // File f = new File(getClass().getResource("/MyResource").toExternalForm());
        //String path = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/excel_List.xlsx").toExternalForm();
        //File file = new File(path);
        OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(file);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
        //FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(new File(excelFile));
       // XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        loadExcel(sheet);
        cacheNames();
      //  fis.close();
        wb.close();
    }
```

If it helps here is the path to the excel file:
src\main\resources\excel_List.xlsx

UPDATE:
so I took the excel file out of the resources folder
\nameOfMyProgram\excel_List.xlsx
and now I get this error.
I tried several versions of using the classLoader, Class and Thread to solve this error from [Different ways of loading a file as an InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676250/different-ways-of-loading-a-file-as-an-inputstream/676273#676273)
but I still cannot get it to compile.

[Error and my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06FKL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to use File object do not put xls-file into resources directory.
Maven puts all files from resources directory into jar.
Java can not create File object based on file in jar-file.
Put your xls-file somewhere in file system and create File object based on its URL.

Since your xls-file is not a resource do not use `getResource`.
Its URL is its full filename (with path).

Comment: Hi. Thank you, but it still does not work. I brought the file out of the resources directory. And now its giving me a FileNOTFoundError error. The URI is set to null. I updated my question above.

Comment: Thank you for your help. That helped me get closer to how to solve it. I posted the code below as an answer so it can easily be used.

Answer (score 0):

**This code below works with jar executable**

```
String path = new File("excel_List.xlsx").getAbsoluteFile().toString();
            File file = new File(path);
            if(!file.exists()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File not found!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(file);
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
```