# Unable to add text file in java eclipse during creation of jar

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created a java project in eclipse and added certain text files like follows

```
FileReader fin=null;
BufferedReader bin=null;
fin=new FileReader("src/main/resources/League.txt");
bin=new BufferedReader(fin);
```

But after creation of the ruunable jar or just simple jar when I run the jar file it is showing that no text file is found or the path is not found. But I have added the text files in the main.resource of my project. How to handle it?

Comment: paths are different in jars http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941754/how-to-get-a-path-to-a-resource-in-a-java-jar-file

Comment: Have you confirmed that the files made it into the jar?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there's a file in the latest Java version directory src\main\resources\League.txt. For example, say for Windows, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\src\main\resources\League.txt. 
**You need to give front slashes**, not back ones. Also, this should be the code:

```
FileReader fin=null;
BufferedReader bin=null;
fin=new FileReader("src\\main\\resources\\League.txt"); // Because of Unicode restrictions. 
bin=new BufferedReader(fin);
```

Maybe you check this as well:  [How to get a path to a resource in a Java JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941754/how-to-get-a-path-to-a-resource-in-a-java-jar-file?lq=1)

Comment: but I have to create a jar file of my project that would be path independant. So what should be the wayout?

Comment: Jar files break hard-coded paths; generally you'll have to use `____.class.getClassLoader().getResource()` or `_____.class.getResource()` along with some path relative to the location of _____ to retrieve the text file. (don't know if the syntax is correct on those, but I think it's fairly close to those)

Answer (score 0):

Use URLClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream, this works in jars and in eclipse...

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Even though the file is in src/resources you need not say src folder in path.

```
BufferedReader br = null;

try {

    String sCurrentLine;

    URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("resources/League.txt");
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (br != null)br.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```