# How can we subscribe to resources in scala?

Tags: scala

How can we subscribe to file present as resource in Scala project so that any live changed to the file can be detected in the the service?
Example there is a Scala code which is calculating sum of numbers from the text file , how to subscribe to that file in the code so that program can act upon immediately for any addition of new numbers in the file.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27360977/how-to-read-files-from-resources-folder-in-scala ?

Answer (score 0):

In Scala you can use Java classes and APIs.
You can use the Java Watch Service API in `java.nio.file`. 
You can about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).