# Not able to access a file using Relative paths in Scala

Tags: java, scala, csv

I've written all the complex mumbo jumbo Scala logic but now I am stuck with a very very basic problem. java.io.FileNotFoundException.

I am trying to read from a csv file & feed that data as input to my Code.

My folder structure is:

```
MainProject 
    AcceptanceTest
        com.myOwn
        nish
            data
                TestData.csv
            pagemodel
            spec
                Test.scala
            util
```

Here's my file reading piece of code:

```
import scala.io.Source
class Test { 
val testDataFile = Source.fromFile("./../data/TestData.csv")
for (line <- testDataFile.getLines().drop(1)) {
    val cols = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
    println(s"${cols(0)}|${cols(1)}|${cols(2)}")
}
```

TestData.csv contains:

```
#ScenarioName, Value1, Value2
Test1, F1, BrightnessDecrease 
Test2, F2, BrightnessIncrease
```

Running Test.scala gives me a java.io.FileNotFoundException. 
If I change my File path to the absolute path, everything works ok.

```
val testDataFile = Source.fromFile("/MainProject/AcceptanceTest/com/myOwn/nish/data/TestData.csv")
```

What is missing in my relative path which I am unable to spot?

Comment: Are you executing from the command line or from an IDE? You can also println(new java.io.File("./").getCanonicalPath) to better understand the current working folder.

Comment: Thanks Pascal. This helped in figuring out what my working directory was! Finally this worked -> "MainProject/AcceptanceTest/com/myOwn/nish/data/TestData.csv"

Answer (score 0):

Put your csv file inside `resources` folder (`src/main/resources`) of the project. now you can access the `file` inside the resources folder using below code snippet from any where inside the `src` package. do not forget to put initial `/`.

```
Source.fromFile(getClass.getResource("/hello.csv").getFile).getLines().foreach(println)
```

for more info [How to read files from resources folder in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27360977/how-to-read-files-from-resources-folder-in-scala)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your suggestions. 
Unfortunately changing the folders structure was not an option, so having a src/main/resource was ruled out (that would probably have been the cleanest solution).

```
val testDataFile = Source.fromFile("MainProject/AcceptanceTest/com/myOwn/nish/data/TestData.csv")
```

The current working directory was the MainProject. So a "/" at the beginning was unnecessary. I figured that out using .getCanonicalPath as suggested by Pascal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with an IDE (intellij-idea in my case), and for some reason, you have imported multiple projects as modules, check the working directory in "Run/Debug Configuration". My code could not find the correct path because the source folder of the project was wrong. The way I realized this, was because I used the absolute path.

By the way, I recommend using os-lib by com-lihaoyi from GitHub.