# Scala JAR File : Efficient way to read data from file in jar

Tags: java, scala, maven, jar

I have written Scala program that is reading some data from file.

```
lazy val vectorOptF2 = Source.fromFile("DataFiles/F2-xopt.txt").getLines().map(_.toDouble). toList
```

When I execute my code in IntelliJ IDEA IDE, It run successfully. But when I created JAR file

```
mvn clean packae
```

and tried to execute JAR file, it throws error stating so such file found.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: DataFiles/F2-xopt.txt (No such file or directory)
```

I have created ZIP file **DataFiles.zip** and move it to JAR file

```
mv DataFiles.zip MyJar.jar
```

but same was error.
How can I read data from files placed inside a folder in JAR file?

- There are multiple files in side Folder **DataFiles** and have to read some of them based on specified criteria each time program executes.

Comment: If the file is inside the **JAR**, it is not longer a file but a resource, you need something like: `Source.fromInputStream(Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("foo/bar"))`

Answer (score 2):

If you are following EAR structure,
add your data files after creating respective directory structures in the `src/main/resources/` directory and read it using the following code.

```
lazy val vectorOptF2 = Source.fromResource
("DataFiles/F2-xopt.txt").getLines().map(_.toDouble). toList
```

Comment: The `fromFile` will not open a resource. You need `getResourceAsStream` or `Source.fromResource` for that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27360977/how-to-read-files-from-resources-folder-in-scala

Comment: @Suma, Updated my answer as per your comments.