# Unable to access files under resources (streamlets)

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, akka-stream

I am trying to access the files under the resource folder while running streamlets.
Below is my sbt structure.

[image]

i want to access files under streamlets -> src -> main -> resources.

i use
`getClass.getClassLoader.getResource(s"file.txt")`
running locally, it's working, but while running in cluster
getting error, no file and directory.
Please assist .

adding build.sbt :-

```
lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).aggregate(streamlets, app)

lazy val streamlets = project.in(file("streamlets"))
  .enablePlugins(CloudflowAkkaPlugin, ScalaxbPlugin)
  .settings(
    name := s"$baseName-streamlets",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "ch.qos.logback" %  "logback-classic" % logbackVersion,
      "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.1.1" % "test",
      "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.1.1" % "test",
      "com.lightbend.akka" %% "akka-stream-alpakka-s3" % alpakkaVersion,
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % akkaVersion,
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % akkaHttpVersion,
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-xml" % akkaHttpVersion,
      "org.glassfish.jaxb" % "jaxb-runtime" % jaxbVersion, // for JDK11
    )
  )

lazy val app = project.in(file("app"))
  .enablePlugins(CloudflowApplicationPlugin)
  .settings(
    name := s"$baseName-dev",
    runLocalConfigFile := Some("app/src/main/resources/local.conf")
  )
  .dependsOn(streamlets)
```

Comment: Are you creating a jar file or using sbt-assemble?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read files from resources folder in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27360977/how-to-read-files-from-resources-folder-in-scala)

Comment: What is the error you are getting? How did you create the that runs in the cluster? Can you attach your `build.sbt`?

Comment: added the sbt structure. i use travis ci to build and create image in jfrog. that image is pulled by cloudflow to run in cluster pod