# Get absolute path of Resource File in a Gradle Plugin?

Tags: java, android, groovy, gradle, build.gradle

I have a Gradle plugin with a task:

```
@TaskAction
def nyTask() {

  def myFlags = project.pluginConfig.myFlags
  if myFlags == null {
    myFlags = "-arg1 absolutePathToFile/file1.txt -arg2 absolutePathToFile/file2.txt"  
    // *** this is the part I don't know ***
  }

  project.exec { 
     executable aCommand
     args myFlags.split()
  }
}
```

`myFlags` is defined in the plugin's extension. When using the plugin I can configure it like:

```
myPlugin {
  myFlags = "-arg1 absolutePathToFile/file1.txt -arg2 absolutePathToFile/file2.txt"
}
```

I have some default files in the plugins `src/main/resources/`folder, i.e.,

```
src/main/resources/file1.txt
src/main/resources/file2.txt
```

If `myFlags == null` then I want to use the files from the resource folder.

The problem is that I do not know how to get the correct path to these files.

**How do I get the absolute path to the file1.txt and file2.txt in the plugin's resource folder?**

Comment: It seems that this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941754/how-to-get-a-path-to-a-resource-in-a-java-jar-file

Answer (score 4):

Absolute path can be accessed via `main` sourceSet [defined](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#source_sets) in java plugin.

The only problem is that in general there may more than one source dir for resources, so in the next example I demonstrate how to get the absolute path of the first resources directory and in your case you need to decide how to handle more then one resources dir:

```
  if myFlags == null {
      def resourcesDir = sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs.first().absolutePath
      myFlags = "-arg1 ${resourcesDir}/file1.txt -arg2 ${resourcesDir}/file2.txt"
  }
```