# Exported Jar file doesn't read the texture files

Tags: java, image, executable-jar

OK, so I've worked upon a Java flappy bird game, the game works fine in the editor it reads all of the textures but when i export it to a .jar file it won't read the textures.

[image]

Thats what it looks like when i launch the game and that's the layout of the .jar file.

[image]

That's how the Eclipse one is set out, I've tried putting the assets folder in the net folder, the dragon4c3 folder the game folder but it still doesn't read the textures, is there something i need to do when exporting the .jar file? It does work but you need to have the assets folder in the same folder as the .jar file. Is that the only way of doing it?

Comment: what is the path given for texture?

Comment: assets/textures/<texture>.png

Comment: looks its a path problem, print absolute path before loading. That would clarify more.

Comment: What do you mean by absolute path? Like C:/Eclipse/Whatever??

Comment: yes @Dragon4c3_, that would make sense.

Comment: D:\Java Workspace\Flappy Bird\assets\textures

Comment: umm... dats the issue.. load it using resource loader http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941754/how-to-get-a-path-to-a-resource-in-a-java-jar-file

Comment: This is my code BufferedImage img = null;
 {
  try {
   img = ImageIO.read(new File("assets/textures/background.png"));
  } catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println("background.png Not Found!!");
  }
 }
 {  What should i do with it now?

Comment: How do i load it using the Resource Loader?

Answer (score 0):

have you selected "Export all output folders for checked projects"?

[image here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/images/create_jar_2.jpg)

Comment: Just did it still no textures.

Comment: In the Export JAR dialog, make sure you select all the necessary resources you want to export. By default, there should be no problem exporting other resource files as well

Comment: Did it, still the same problem.