# Failing to load resource when running java program from command line

Tags: java, url, intellij-idea, xsd, resources

I am able to run a java program from within my IDE (IntelliJ) properly; however, when I attempt to run the same program from the command line it fails. The error being thrown is:

```
RuntimeUnmarshallException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'file:/home/Experiments/file:/home/path/to/jar/my.jar!/configuration.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

The stack trace points out that the issue is here:

```
String SCHEMA_FILE_PATH = "configuration.xsd";
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
URL resource = classLoader.getResource(SCHEMA_FILE_PATH); // <- breaks here
return new File(resource.getFile());
```

I have the schema file that cannot be found stored in a directory that is marked as a resource root in my IDE. I am betting that when I run from the command line that since I am running from a different working directory that it does not know where to look. I have tried setting the classpath on the command line to be able to look in the directory that contains the schema, but this did not help. I imagine that I could set the working directory to what it is when I run from my IDE, but this seems like a horrible design choice.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: I just confirmed that the configuration.xsd file is contained in the jar, but for whatever reason it seems to be looking for it in weird places...

Comment: Do you run the packaged `.jar`?

Comment: Yes. I ran it using the following command: `java -jar path/to/the.jar --input something`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running a `.jar`, its content is not unpacked, but read directly from the `.jar`. Therefore the resource you are loading can not be represented as a `File` (it is still nested inside the `.jar`). You can see that in the error message -  the part after the exclamation mark is the path to the resource inside the `jar`.

I would recommend using [`Classloader.getResourceAsStream(..)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) instead. It handles the loading transparently.

Note that you can use [`new StreamSource(InputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html#StreamSource-java.io.InputStream-) to construct a reference to the schema document from the stream.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html#res_names) is some official information about resource loading, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941754/how-to-get-a-path-to-a-resource-in-a-java-jar-file) question may be of interest.