# Google Spread Sheet Spark library

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using https://github.com/potix2/spark-google-spreadsheets library for reading the spread sheet file in spark. It is working perfectly in my local.

```
val df = sqlContext.read.
    format("com.github.potix2.spark.google.spreadsheets").
    option("serviceAccountId", "xxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com").
    option("credentialPath", "/path/to/credentail.p12").
    load("<spreadsheetId>/worksheet1")
```

I created a new assembly jar with included all the credentials and use that jar for reading the file. But I am facing issue with reading the credentialPath file. I tried using

```
getClass.getResourceAsStream("/resources/Aircraft/allAircraft.txt")
```

But library only supports absolute path. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: It might be because it's a rather bad idea to put credentials into a jar. Pass it along via ENV or deploy it separately.

Comment: @Reactormonk, Can you provide me some suggestions//link how to use with ENV. thakns

Comment: Possibly related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/205606/strategy-for-keeping-secret-info-such-as-api-keys-out-of-source-control

Comment: @Reactormonk I will check and let you know. Thanks for the share

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--files` argument of `spark-submit` or `SparkContext.addFile()` to distribute a credential file. If you want to get a local path of the credential file in worker node, you should call `SparkFiles.get("credential filename")`.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkFiles

// you can also use `spark-submit --files=credential.p12`
sqlContext.sparkContext.addFile("credential.p12")
val credentialPath = SparkFiles.get("credential.p12")

val df = sqlContext.read.
    format("com.github.potix2.spark.google.spreadsheets").
    option("serviceAccountId", "xxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com").
    option("credentialPath", credentialPath).
    load("<spreadsheetId>/worksheet1")
```

Comment: Thank you so much .I will try and let you know . Btw is it possible to update sheet using this library.

Answer (score 0):

Use SBT and try [typesafe config library](https://github.com/typesafehub/config).

Here is a [simple but complete sample](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/tree/master/examples/scala/simple-app/src/main) which reads some information from the config file placed in `resources` folder.

Then you can assemble a jar file using [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin.

Comment: It really easy to manage confiuraton using typesafe config library. Thanks for that. But I really want to get the file location of the file from jar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941754/how-to-get-a-path-to-a-resource-in-a-java-jar-file. Is it possible using typesafe. I could not find a way to do that. @amirkarimi

Comment: As you said the library just supports absolute path. What about getting the resource as stream and then write it to a physical file and give the file path to the library? It might have some serious security issues, though.

Comment: BTW, try this: Give this as credentialPath: `ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/resources/...").toURI()`.

Comment: Writing in to the temporary file is working.Is there any better solution apart from this. I  tried ClasssLoader approach too.. but no luck . thanks

Comment: I checked out the source code of the library and I think this is the last solution. The library can be patched to allow creating `File` instance from other sources. [Here](https://github.com/potix2/spark-google-spreadsheets/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/potix2/spark/google/spreadsheets/DefaultSource.scala#L59) is the code which converts the `credentialPath` to a `File` instance. It would be a great opportunity to contribute to a Scala library ;)

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestions.I am bit new to scala. But I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in the Databricks environment, you can [upload the credentials file](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data.html).

Setting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable, [as described here](https://github.com/juampynr/google-spreadsheet-reader), does not get you around this requirement because it's a link to the file path, not the actual credentials.  See [here](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/read-google-sheets-dataframe/) for more details about getting the right credentials and using the library.