# null value for a ressource in Java

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I would like to put ressources in my JAR file but, there is a problem when I want to use it. If I show the path with this code :

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, MyStaticClass.class.getResource("/ressources/") + "file.File" + i, "OK", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                File file = new File(MyStaticClass.class.getResource("/ressources/") + "file.File" + i);
```

The result of messagebox is `jar:file:/home/clement/Bureau/Untitled.jar!/ressources/niveau.Niveau1` and the exeption

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: jar:file:/home/clement/Bureau/Untitled.jar!/ressources/file.File1 (No file or folder of this type)
```

The files are in the src folder in src/ressources/file.File1

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941754/how-to-get-a-path-to-a-resource-in-a-java-jar-file

Answer (score 0):

`getResourceAsStream()` returns an `InputStream`. Your code basically tries to find file '/ressources/' which is not a file but a directory, so `getResourceAsStream()` returns `null` for it.

There is no point in printing an `InputStream`. What you could do is something like this:

```
InputStream is = MyStaticClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/ressources/" + "file.File1")
```

And then read its contents (for example, using `InputStream`'s `read()` methods, or wrap it with an `InputStreamReader` and use it's `read()`. It's hard to give more advice as I don't know what you'd like to do with what you read.

**An update for updated question code follows**

`getResource()` returns a `URL` instance, which does not suit for printing as well (and for concatenating using + operator). But you can convert it to `File` instance if you like with help of `getFile()` method:

```
File file = new File(MyStaticClass.class.getResource("/ressources/" + "file.File" + i).getFile());
```

Please also note that `getResource()` is called on full resource name and not just directory name.

Then you could work with that `File` instance.

But if you just want to read the resource contents, you could do something like the following (with no need to get `URL` instance):

```
InputStream is = MyStaticClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/ressources/" + "file.File1")
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"));
try {
    if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    }
} finally {
    scanner.close();
}
```

This example assumes that your file is a text file and has at least one line. It prints that line to the console.

Comment: I edited the question because It was an other code I tried. Thanks.