# Java inputstream from a relative path

Tags: java, csv, inputstream, fileinputstream

I'm trying to write a static function that reads a CSV and output a value from that said CSV.
I'm having trouble reading it because every time I get a fileNotFound exeception, however I believe my path is correct.

Here's the code

```
public class DateFormatUtils {

  private static String dateFormatCsvPath = "csv/country_date_format.csv";

  public static String getDateFormatByLocale(Locale Locale) {
    List<Map<String, String>> mapList = Collections.emptyList();
    String fileExtension = "csv";
    try {
      InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(dateFormatCsvPath);
      mapList = ExcelUtils.read(inputStream, fileExtension);
      String a = "a";

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "a";
  }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of my project, you can see that relatively from my class, the file is under `csv/country_date_format.csv`. I also tried `./csv/country_date_format.csv` and `/country_date_format.csv` with no avail.

I also tried to get my file as a resource but without success too as such
`String path = DateFormatUtils.class.getClass().getResource("csv/country_date_format.csv").getPath()`

I don't understand why I still get the file not found exception. Anyone can enlighten me?

The csv and the rest of the code is bundled inside a JAR

[image]

Comment: I suggest right-mouse-click on the csv file then choose 'File path' and then copy the path in the explorer screen that opens, paste this in your code and change all the \ to /

Comment: use `String currentWorkingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");` to get running application working dir and specify path including that.

Comment: @onkarruikar that would help me build an absolute path but id rather use a relative one

Comment: @Abra  that would help me build an absolute path but id rather use a relative one

Comment: Current working dir returned by the API will change when you change the executable location. You are not hard coding the absolute path this way.

Comment: @onkarruikar the `System.getProperty("user.dir")` gives me the path of the folder when my JAR is aka `/User/proj/jar` instead of the root of my project which is `/User/proj/code/`

and eventhough it would give me my working directory, there is a lot of folders from the root `/User/proj/code/` to my CSV file, so i will have no choice but to hardcode like `System.getProperty("user.dir") + /folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD/ + fileName`. Hence why im looking for something relative and not absolute.

Comment: `InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/mycompany/utils/csv/xyz.csv");` In OP please mention that the file is inside a jar.

Comment: @onkarruikar this looks very hardcoded to me :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a path to a resource in a Java JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941754/how-to-get-a-path-to-a-resource-in-a-java-jar-file)