# Configuration file is within the JAR. How to put the configuration file outside the JAR?

Tags: java, spring

When I create a Java Spring application, the spring.xml configuration file is usually in the src folder. When I export this application as a runnable JAR, the spring.xml file goes inside the JAR. But I don't want the jar to be extracted and only want the contents of spring.xml to be changed when necessary.

But since the XML is inside the JAR, it means I am changing the JAR file when I change the contents of spring.xml. How to get around this? Is it possible to have the spring.xml outside the JAR?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775389/accessing-properties-files-outside-the-jar

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can take the `spring.xml` out of the JAR, and then you can reference it from your app in a few ways, either as a resource using `file:` or on the classpath with `classpath:`.

For example, in `web.xml` you can now do:

```
<!-- if spring.xml is on the classpath -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:spring.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

...or:

```
<!-- if spring.xml is at a known location -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>file:/tmp/spring.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**UPDATE**

Please note that I'm answering your question, but would recommend using a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` instead (presuming you only want to change properties).

Otherwise, if your context is going to fundamentally change, you may as well keep it in the JAR where the versioned changes denotes a new binary.

Comment: But I would have to know file:/tmp/spring.xml in advance, right?

Comment: I'm sure you can do a relative location too, but I can't remember from the top of my head relative to what exactly.