# How to make JAR access properties files outside of it?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jar, properties-file

I made an EJB project and put it in the lib folder of a Dynamic Web Project on eclipse. This jar (the EJB) uses 2 properties file. Those 2 are supposed to be outside of the .jar (there are values written on them on runtime and no option to use DB). The web application deploys but the files cannot be accesed.

Now I know that in "Run Configurations" something can be done, but this is not a runnable jar but an EJB Project with a class, so the jar is like a Class Library.

How can i include this properties files in the classpath so they can be accesed from outside the JAR? Or there's another option for this?

PD: (Below, the EJB and the properties)
[image: The EJB and the properties files]

PD2: (The error I get)

> 15:03:49,480 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-1) java.io.FileNotFoundException: log_prueba.properties (El sistema no puede hallar el archivo especificado)

Here's the code for the function I use to read the properties:

> ```
> public void funcionPrueba()
> {
>     PropertyConfigurator.configure("log_prueba.properties");
>     Random ran = new Random();
>     logger.info("Inicia prueba");
>     try
>     {
>         FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("Test.properties");
>         Properties props = new Properties();
>         props.load(in);
>         in.close();
> ```

```
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Test.properties");

        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            props.setProperty("Q.QUEUE.REQ.01", "QL.COLA.REQ." + ran.nextInt(100));
            props.setProperty("Q.QUEUE.RES.01", "QL.COLA.RES." + ran.nextInt(100));
            logger.debug("propiedad 01:" + props.getProperty("Q.QUEUE.REQ.01"));
            logger.debug("propiedad 02:" + props.getProperty("Q.QUEUE.RES.01"));
            props.store(out, null);
        }

        out.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        logger.error("Error - Exception:" + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing properties files outside the .jar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775389/accessing-properties-files-outside-the-jar)

Comment: and your code used to access them?

Comment: I'll update that. As for that post, wasn't very clear to me, RC.